# deprecated .item() in pandas and alternative way to rewrite this

Tags: pandas

I am not very good at pandas, and have a line of code that gives a warning that its going to be deprecated in later versions. The .item() is the victim here.

```
orderTotal = eachOrderDF.loc[eachOrderDF['ITEM CODE'] == 'Order Total', 'ORDER QTY(PKS)'].item()
```

Is there another way to rewrite this code to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select first value of filtered `Series` with [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html), [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or convert to array and select first value :

```
s = eachOrderDF.loc[eachOrderDF['ITEM CODE'] == 'Order Total', 'ORDER QTY(PKS)']

orderTotal = s.iat[0]
```

---

```
orderTotal = s.iloc[0]
```

---

```
orderTotal = s.values[0]
```

But if possible no match, it means `s` is empty `Series` solution above failed. Then working solution is use `next` with `iter` for possible specify value if no match, here `no match`:

```
orderTotal = next(iter(s), 'no match')
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I used iat as you have suggested in this case.